# Is it possible to add time input check for text field with pure react way?

Tags: reactjs

In order to add input data check to a time range input element like this:

**(We don't use one input field but different input to time unit for good visualization)**

[image]

I want to validate the value if it is number and in the allowed range for different text fields.

I see there is a [react-time-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-time-picker) package but I want to do it with pure react way such as state check, is it possible?

In fact if we can do the left half range check will be used for the right part. Since even `23:59 - 23:59` is allowed in the real world.

---

I tried this way:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2" name="startHour" min="0" max="23">
```

But still can input 25 in the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a controlled version of the [browser's native time input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) and parse its value (which is in `hh:mm` format, regardless of user locale or how the input is presented). Then use those parsed values however you want. Here's a demonstration:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.time-input { font-size: 1rem; }
.states { margin-top: 1rem; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import {useMemo, useState} from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules instead of the commented import statments above
const {useMemo, useState} = React;

function App () {
  const [rawTime, setRawTime] = useState('00:00');

  const [hours, minutes] = useMemo(
    () => rawTime.split(':').slice(0, 2).map(Number),
    [rawTime],
  );

  const statesJson = JSON.stringify({
    rawTime,
    hours,
    minutes,
  }, null, 2);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="time-input"
        type="time"
        onChange={ev => setRawTime(ev.target.value)}
        value={rawTime}
      />
      <div className="states">
        <label>States:</label>
        <pre>
          <code>{statesJson}</code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```

Comment: I want to input hour and minute in different input fields. Just number is allowed.

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra Why are separate input fields important? Please update your question with this new criteria and reasoning.

Comment: I added the reason to the question: `We don't use one input field but different input to time unit for good visualization`.